# Toggle display:none to all tags in JavaScript (no jQuery) without classes : is it possible?

Tags: javascript, toggle

I've read similar posts but i only found where it says to add class to the HTML to do what i want, so, basically i have a button, that when i want to click it hides ALL code HTML tags, and when i click it again it shows them. Since i have a lot of code tags in a page it would take me quite a lot to add a class to each one. I've been trying a few things such as

```
if(document.getElementsByTagName("CODE").style.display === "block"){
document.getElementsByTagName("CODE").style.display = "none"
}
```

and something around that, all similar code, but they all either made my browser crash or didn't work. My question is, is it really a MUST to use the class name and check for the class name of it's possible to compare, as i "did" above in the code here, the display content of all tags? ( maybe looping with a for loop each element, i tried that too, with no result. )
i tried every possible thing with my few knowledge so far ( im still studying javascript ). I would really like to know if i am trying to do something really advanced or i just dont see how it can be done.

Thanks, i hope there wasnt another question like this, i've read all of the ones suggested and none ( except one it said to use class ) was like this.

They all recommend to add classes, so i feel like im trying to do something really impossible. Im not into jQuery yet, so dont talk about it please, thanks. ( first i must learn for good JavaScript )

Comment: document.getElementsByTagName(), as the name of the function suggests, returns an array of elements, so you need to iterate through it to make checks and set values

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to iterate through the results of `document.getElementsByTagName("CODE")`, it is an array-like variable. It is a jQuery feature that lets you write `.css()` to a list of objects and have them all processed. You need something like

```
ar = document.getElementsByTagName("code");
for (i = 0; i < ar.length; ++i)
   ar[i].style.display = "none";
```

If you need to toggle `code` visibility, use this code

```
ar = document.getElementsByTagName("code"); 
for (i = 0; i < ar.length; ++i)
{ 
   if(ar[i].style.display != "none") //the element is visible
   {
      ar[i].style.display = "none";
   } 
   else
   {
      ar[i].style.display = "block"; //If you need to make it block explicitly, otherwise ""
   } 
}
```

Note that the `style.display` property is initially empty and defaults to `inline` for `code` tag but can be set explicitly to other values. Resetting it to `''` results in restoring the state.

If you need to change the visibility back and forth without the modification of display *mode*, you need to save the previous mode (`code` tags can be displayed not only in `block` mode). Can be done like this:

```
ar = document.getElementsByTagName("code"); 
for (i = 0; i < ar.length; ++i)
{ 
   if(ar[i].style.display != "none") //the element is visible, "" or "blocK" or some other value
   {
      ar[i].saved_display = ar[i].style.display; //Save the display mode to a new property of the tag
      ar[i].style.display = "none"; //And hide the element
   } 
   else
   {
      if (typeof ar[i].saved_display === "undefined") //It's the first time we see the element. Display it in default mode
         ar[i].style.display = "";
      else
         ar[i].style.display = ar[i].saved_display; //We know how the element was shown before we hid it, restoring
   } 
}
```

Comment: Technically, it's an array-like, not an array. The difference is that most of the array methods are not present.

Comment: `ar = document.getElementsByTagName("code");
for (i = 0; i < ar.length; ++i){
if(ar[i].style.display === "block";){
ar[i].style.display = "none";}
else{
ar[i].style.display = "block";}
}
}`

i'm still confused at this "if(ar[i].style.display === "block";" it seems like i cant achieve it, thats whats blocking me i guess. am i really trying the impossible?

Comment: I have modified my answer.
And yes, technically the result of `getElementsByTagName` is not an array and lacks the method that is most useful here - `forEach()`.

Comment: Thanks, i didnt think that display didnt inherit anything and it was empty, tahts where i failed i guess.

Comment: @Aneri—just because an element's *style.display* has no value does not mean the element is visible. It might not be visible due to CSS rules or hiding of a parent element. Also `ar[i].saved_display === "undefined"` is not suitable as DOM objects are not required to support non–standard properties, far better to set a *className* or *data-* property value and check that.

Answer (score 1):

As Aneri says, [*getElementsByTagName*](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-A6C9094) returns a [NodeList](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-536297177) that you can iterate over by index.

Note that the *display* property only has a value if it's been explicitly set, it does not inherit a value from CSS so you should do something like the following, which will hide all the CODE elements if their display hasn't been set to *none* and display them if it has:

```
var element, elements = document.getElementsByTagName("CODE");

for (var i=0, iLen=elements.length; i<iLen; i++) {
  element = elements[i];

  // If element hasn't been hidden, hide it
  if (element.style.display == '') {
    element.style.display = 'none';

  // Otherwise show it
  } else {
    element.style.display = '';
  }
}
```

Note that you should return the display value to "" (empty string) so that the elements return to their default or inherited value, which might not be "block".

Also, child elements will be hidden if their parent element has *display: none*.

Comment: Thanks too, i chose the other guy because he was first and  but your answer is valid too. I got tricked by a CSS factor. Next time i will analyze everything i try to do to troubleshoot the problem. Thanks very much you too.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a class just to `BODY` or `HTML` element and attach needed styles to this class via e.g. context selectors. For example:

```css
HTML.hide-code CODE {display: none; }
```